# Interpreting constant kernal panic

Tags: mac, macos, kernel-panic

I have very frequent kernel panic calls.

Here is a report on one of them.

I have no idea what is causing it.

```
Fri Jun 27 11:21:45 2014
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff7fad305f7c): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 3 0 a0 d9 9 8 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0x102c00000 0xffffff813c9b8000 0x0e7150a2, D0, P3/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.5.26/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
[…]
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[B889D3AB-CCC0-3FCD-A83E-D2E3E4CB537B]@0xffffff7fab95b000->0xffffff7fab992fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[244D4E48-78E6-3369-8D76-285C66EF9BF4]@0xffffff7fab6be000
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.5.26)[B67CD59F-1344-37BC-8A9A-46D6D3DCA13D]@0xffffff7fad2f7000->0xffffff7fad30afff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.5.26)[C0F9A79F-167E-3A68-873C-5CE17B97FB11]@0xffffff7fad2ef000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[045D5D6F-AD1E-36DB-A249-A346E2B48E54]@0xffffff7fac2f2000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[244D4E48-78E6-3369-8D76-285C66EF9BF4]@0xffffff7fab6be000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[B889D3AB-CCC0-3FCD-A83E-D2E3E4CB537B]@0xffffff7fab95b000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.0.4)[E04639C5-D734-3AB3-A682-FE66694C6653]@0xffffff7fad2f2000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(8.2.6)[DB59C243-61DE-3B0C-86C3-6D89446F6F14]@0xffffff7fab9b4000->0xffffff7fabc27fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[244D4E48-78E6-3369-8D76-285C66EF9BF4]@0xffffff7fab6be000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[B93BBFC9-9ED5-3DDD-8CED-5EDA081BB997]@0xffffff7fab99e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[B889D3AB-CCC0-3FCD-A83E-D2E3E4CB537B]@0xffffff7fab95b000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.5.26)[E971FED4-805F-3462-9D93-1919EBE3DC82]@0xffffff7fab9ae000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal(8.2.6)[AE5D65B5-1E26-3509-97B9-C68D97C21143]@0xffffff7fabc33000->0xffffff7fabddffff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(8.2.6)[DB59C243-61DE-3B0C-86C3-6D89446F6F14]@0xffffff7fab9b4000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[244D4E48-78E6-3369-8D76-285C66EF9BF4]@0xffffff7fab6be000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
13D65

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.2.0: Thu Apr 17 23:03:13 PDT 2014; root:xnu2422.100.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: ADD73AE6-88B0-32FB-A8BB-4F7C8BE4092E
Kernel slide:     0x000000002ae00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802b000000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 3525601653

last loaded kext at 3285490337: com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0 (addr 0xffffff7faca77000, size 45056)
loaded kexts:
[…]
```

Comment: This is going to need an edit to be readable. Please compose a short sentence at the beginning to explain what you know or don't know about kernel panics (search here - there are several great explanations of the basics) and what you want to accomplish. Then paste the panic text and embed it as a code sample to avoid posting lines and lines of unformatted output.

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/can-someone-help-me-read-this-crash-report-as-a-user for an example of the edit that would make this helpful to us to help you. Also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95764/how-i-can-read-macbook-crash-report

Comment: @bmike  I tried to edit most of the irrelevant information out. In this case I would say it is the Nvida making the problem. Starting in Safe mode would prove that.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Good first stab. In the future, don't call out edits to the text - just make the post read clearly. Like when a professional editor edits a novel. You only read the result - not the deltas. The system tracks edits if people want to know why / why an edit was made. Let's see what the OP needs when they edit it for what they want to have happen...

Comment: @Ryan I've attempted to fix the formatting of the panic log, but if I've done it wrong please feel free to edit further.

Comment: Thank you all, is the formatting better now?

Comment: Hey, for those interested, it appears to be an issue with the external graphics card. Forcing and keeping the laptop using the integrated card appears to be working.. Workaround until i can stomach the logic board replacement.. You can download gfxCardStatus to manually switch over to the integrated card.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try to narrow it down.

- Start in Safe mode (hold shift) to exclude the GPU and 3d party
- Use Apple Hardware Test (hold D) to check for problems
- Reset your [NVRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379)
- last not least reinstall osx

Answer (score 0):

Your MacBook Pro likely has a faulty discrete GPU. So many of this model have the issue that Apple created a repair program for them, but it expired Dec 31, 2016: https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/.  See http://www.howapple.com/question/35715 for more discussion.